# Modelling a bottle?

Tags: 3d, cinema4d, sketchup

I'm trying to model a bottle made for sunscreen in SketchUp **Make**, however Cinema 4D works too. I am proficient enough at the programs to make basic circular shapes, but there's a slanted edge at the top of the bottle, that is gatekeeping me from finishing the model. I've seen numerous modelling tutorials and I still don't know how to do it. (luckily, I'm not pursuing graphic design)

Here's a picture of the bottle
[image]

Comment: If you are going to utilize easily a photo of an item when you draw a profile to be extruded or revolved you should shoot the photo from further, say from 3 meters if the item is 15...20 centimeters high. Otherwise - like in your case - the imaging projection is far too much off from an easy to trace parallel projection. You need a high quality camera and a tripod to do it, one can forget using a phone. Any CAD or artistic 3D drawing program allows you to draw the revolved profile easily for illustration purposes. A bottle factory ready engineering drawing is totally different case.

Comment: (continued) But you have quite many measures. There should be no problems in drawing the revolution profile good enough for illustration purposes. For it one can guess roundings from the photo. To get something usable you should tell what obstacle prevents you to use the measured dimensions to draw the revolution profile? Here's an example in freeware CAD. The roundings are guessed and there's no cap hinge. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaVux.png